# div height occupy remaining browser window with a non-fixed overall height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I can get Alvaro's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/S8g4E/955/ to work the way I want it to only for width but not height ... my lower component canvas is very large (5000px square) and I want it to scroll in both directions, but have the "viewport" grow to the full size of its containing lower window ...

If you look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tconway556/4LCj2/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="up">Text<br />Text<br />Text<br /></div>
    <div id="down" style="overflow:scroll; width: 100%;">
       <canvas width="5000px" height="5000px">
       </canvas>
   </div>
</div>

#container { width: 100%; height: 300px; border:1px solid red;}
#up { background: green; height:80px}
#down { background:pink; height: calc(100% - 80px); }
```

the width is working as I want. but not the height. I can only hard code the height of the overall container to a fixed value.

If you resize the browser with my fiddle in it, the width of canvas viewport adapts to the containing window, but the height remains fixed. This makes sense since I fixed it at 300px .. but ...

If I replace the fixed 300px with 100% in the #container, the height grows to 5000px + .... what I wanted was the same behavior we see with width. ie. When you resize the outer browser window both width and height of the viewport adapt to the browser boundaries ...

Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Im just replying from a phone so can't look at your fiddle and resize etc but if I understand your problem correctly you could try removing the height value and instead using padding-bottom: with a percentage value. 
You'll have to play around with the values for padding-bottom to see what works for your needs but this will allow the height to adjust dynamically and should scale with your resizing window.  Its a bit of a trial a d error one but ive used it before to solve a similar issue

Comment: good suggestion, but no joy on using bottom-padding:1%, either for the #container or the lower div. that bottom canvas really "wants" to be 5000px high ...